# How to retrieve input field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I get input field for updating a task? When trying to 
        `dd(Request::input('task'));` I get **"Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller {

public function update($id)
{
    dd(Request::input('task'));
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    $task->title = Request::input('task');
    $task->save();
    return Redirect::to('tasks');
}
```

Edit view (its working ok)

```
{!! Form::model($task, array('url' => 'tasks/'.$task->id, 'method' => 'PATCH')) 
    !!}
    {!! Form::text('task', $task->task, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Just saying, you can format code inline by wrapping it in backticks (`\``) and it'll make it look like code instead of emphasized text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Dependency Injection for this:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $task->title = $request->input('task');
    //
}
```

Please see the docs for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Comment: thx, I will need to look at that. I am watching Jeffrey Way tutorials but I dont understand that specific part so i  just tried something very basic.

Comment: Laravel 5 is a great way to help developers stick to a set of standards. DI is extremely useful, and I much prefer them from Facades (not that I have any complaints about them). So yes, refer to as much as you can regarding the way in which L5 does things - your learning experience will be highly advantageous. :-)

Answer (score 17):

You imported the wrong `Request`.

To use the `Request` *facade* you have to do:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request
```

Or just the alias:

```
use Request
```

---

You could also use dependency injection like this:

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function update($id){
        $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
        $task->title = $this->request->input('task');
        $task->save();
        return Redirect::to('tasks');
    }
}
```

Or only use DI on that one method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    $task->title = $request->input('task');
    $task->save();
    return Redirect::to('tasks');
}
```